# Passing multiple values in java

Tags: java

Im new to java. This is my first java code using parser, i was able to check the node value of particular tag by

`if(name != null && name.equals("Length"))`

how to pass multiple values in name value like name.equals("Length","Length1","Length3")), i have to check around 2000 values

below is partial code

```
      if (file.exists()) { 
          Document doc = db.parse(file); 
          Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement(); 

          NodeList Line = docEle.getElementsByTagName("Lineno");
          System.out.println("size " + Line.getLength());

          if(Line != null && Line.getLength() > 0)
          {                      
            if(doc1.getDocumentElement() == null)
            {
                Element root1 = doc1.createElement("Line");    
                doc1.appendChild(root1);   
            }
            for(int j = 0 ;j < nodeValue.getLength();j++)
            {
               Element el = (org.w3c.dom.Element) nodeValue.item(j);
               String name = el.getAttribute("name");
               String value = el.getAttribute("void");
               String valueFromNode = el.getTextContent();
               if(name != null && name.equals("id"))
               {
                  ITEMID =valueFromNode; 
               }
               if(name != null && name.equals("Length"))
               {
                //  System.out.println("This has datcode " + ele);
                  datecode = "Yes";
                  cwi = valueFromNode;
                //  doc1.getDocumentElement().appendChild(doc1.importNode(imported, true));    
                }
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can put all the values in a list, iterate throught the list and check if you have found a value :)

Comment: you could perhaps use a "while" loop..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by filling your lengths values into `ArrayList`, then ask if the name contains that array.

**For Example:**

```
ArrayList<String> lengths = new ArrayList<String>();
//add all lengths values into array

if(lengths.contains(name){ 
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all the values in an ArrayList and use `.contains()`:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("Length");
```

And then:

```
if (name != null && strings.contains(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I would need to compare single `String` with large collection for it existance in it, i would use `HashSet<String>`.
Insteed of testing equality, I would check if my `String` object is in my set. If it does - than it is equal.

```
HashSet<String> compSet=new HashSet<String>();
//put strings to comparision
if(name!=null && compSet.contains(name)){
//hey it was equal.
}
```

Comment: The best way to lern how to swim? Throw onto deep water :)

Comment: Also.. Nothing is mentioned about the elements being unique.. Assumptions are dangerous :)

Comment: But what is the difference if my target is equal with second or 10th element of collection - guess that these elements were the same;]